# WPF CheckBox checked event on scrolling thought datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, events, checkbox, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` containing a `CheckBox`. I create the column like this:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn cTemplateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
cTemplateColumn.Header = "Auswahl";
FrameworkElementFactory cFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
Binding b1 = new Binding("[__intern_cv__]");
//b1.IsAsync = true;
b1.Converter = new StringToBoolConverter(this);
b1.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
b1.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
cFactory.SetValue(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, b1);
cFactory.SetValue(CheckBox.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
cFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CheckedEvent));
cFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.UncheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CheckedEvent));
cFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.PreviewMouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(checkBoxMouseDown));
DataTemplate cCellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
cCellTemplate.VisualTree = cFactory;
cTemplateColumn.CellTemplate = cCellTemplate;    
Columns.Add(cTemplateColumn);
```

Now i have the problem, that during scrolling throught the `DataGrid`, the `CheckedEvent` is called, with `Checked == False`.

The vents a subscripted here:

```
cFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CheckedEvent));
cFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.UncheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CheckedEvent));
```

How can scrolling call the event?

maybe someone has an idea, thank you!

Comment: Just a suggestion. You should not construct your views by code in WPF. Use XAML markup instead.

Comment: Why sould i not do that? Because i feel more comfortable with c# than with XAML :)

Comment: Well, you don't have to do that. As I said, it's only a suggestion. XAML does make things a lot easier if you know how to use it, because it is more readable and declarative.

Answer (score 1):

By default the `DataGrid` virtualizes its rows. This means that during scrolling old rows are re-used with new data. If the new data has `"[__intern_cv__]"` set to false, while the previous data had it set to true an `Unchecked` event will be raised.